# HyLang : Howto simplest for loop in hy?

Tags: hy

I wanna get Hy!

How, In Hylang, do I do the simple Python loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Hi please check https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/api.html#for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [tutorial](https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#basic-operations) provides this example:

```
(for [x [1 2 3]]
  (print x))         ; => 1 2 3
```

Changing the variable name, and using `range` in place of a list, we get:

```
(for [i (range 5)]
  (print i))
```

Comment: My brain turned back on at 17:30.  Sorry for dumbing.